# How to sync XML comments between C# parent classes/interfaces and child classes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, documentation, xml-documentation

In Java, if I have a Javadoc on a parent class or interface, then the Javadoc appears in the context of a child class or interface in most IDEs when I hover over the child class name. However, this doesn't seem to be true in Visual Studio with C#'s XML comments. Is there any way to automatically sync the XML comments between parent and child classes, so I don't have to copy/paste them and sync them manually?

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a library that other projects will use, then you have a great option available with Sandcastle Help File Builder's (SHFB) [`<inheritdoc>`](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/SHFB/docs-master/XMLCommentsGuide/html/86453FFB-B978-4A2A-9EB5-70E118CA8073.htm) tag. While Visual Studio doesn't natively understand this tag, SHFB provides an [IntelliSense Component](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/SHFB/docs-master/SandcastleBuilder/html/5d546511-6aec-455a-ba09-9daffb124c6d.htm) that reads the XML documentation file produced by your project, and writes out a new XML documentation file with all `<inheritdoc>` tags replaced by the inherited documentation. This is exactly the process we use for shipping the XML documentation for the openstack.net SDK on NuGet:

1. [Create XML documentation during the build.](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/3c6660e1145b676c102f873b67f6acd8f15fb9d2/src/corelib/corelib.v4.0.csproj#L36)

   [image]
2. [Include the IntelliSense Component in our SHFB project.](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/3c6660e1145b676c102f873b67f6acd8f15fb9d2/src/Documentation/Documentation.v4.0.shfbproj#L60-L64)

   [image: Configure IntelliSense Component]
3. Create a .nuspec file (NuGet Package Specification) that [explicitly references the XML documentation created by the IntelliSense Component](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/3c6660e1145b676c102f873b67f6acd8f15fb9d2/src/corelib/corelib.nuspec#L39) instead of the documentation created by the C# compiler.

While inside Visual Studio, it's also beneficial to be able to see the documentation for base classes. I use the [Inheritance Margin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a55d546-0cb2-4991-a002-e6be8ce09f08) extension to jump from an overriding or implementing method to the base class or interface where it is fully documented.

Comment: "Intellisense Component"? Will that work with the Express version of Visual Studio? And what if I'm referencing the library within another project in the same solution, as opposed to via a DLL?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio doesn't provide this out of the box. There's no way to keep them in sync, or to make derived types inherit XML documentation.

But if you have [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) installed, it will give you the option to copy XML comments from the base type to the derived type.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really an answer... at all. Firstly, Resharper only displays that option if the function has no documentation to begin with. If the documentation is simply outdated, the option isn't even displayed. Secondly, resharper provides no way to do this operation for an entire file. I don't know about anyone else but I would not consider it a "sync" if I have to go in and clear the comments for the exact functions I need and recopy them with resharper every single time. That's barely an advantage over doing them by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I built a tool to post-process the XML documentation files to add support for the <inheritdoc/> tag.

While it doesn't help with Intellisense in source code, it does allow the modified XML documentation files to be included in a NuGet package and therefore works with Intellisense in referenced NuGet packages.

It's at www.inheritdoc.io (free version available).